# MySQL - Can connect via localhost but not via 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server running on Debian (`Server version: 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 (Debian)`). Everything worked fine until rebooting the server. Now I can only connect to my MySQL server via localhost, whereas via 127.0.0.1 doesn't work:

`$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` gives me `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

I have port 3306 open in the firewall and the server seems to be listening on 3306:

```
$ netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State        PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       20877/mysqld
```

Connecting to 3306 with telnet doesn't seem to work, neither (for both localhost and 127.0.0.1):

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

In my `my.cnf` I have `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`, which shouldn't be the problem...

In `/etc/hosts` there are these lines

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

I am just not able to find the error, do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it **as** an answer. Not edit your question's title/body. I'd suggest you write it up as an answer and post that, then *roll back* the edit to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I have re-edited my question and posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that TCP-Wrappers were denying the connection to 127.0.0.1. Solved by adding `mysqld: 127.0.0.1` to the `/etc/hosts.allow`-file.